# Why is loop adding NA values to the data frame?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I have a basic while and for loop, I iterate through some starting and ending values in a dataframe, then go through a list and grab (substring) some values.

The problem with the below code is that it adds a lot of NA rows which I don't understand why and how.

I have an if which looks at the GREPL- finds "TRACK 2 DATA: ", if so then ads a row in dataframe. I don't have an else which adds NA values. So in my understanding in case if Block is false, the iteration should continue and not add values to dataframe?

What might be wrong?

```
i=1
fundi <- nrow(find_txn)  #get the last record
while(i <=fundi) {                  # Start while-loop until END OF records
  nga <- find_txn[i,1]  #FRom record
  ne <- find_txn[i,3]  #to Records 
  
  for (j in nga:ne){ #For J in from:to 
    
    if(grepl("TRACK 2 DATA: ",linn[j])) { #If track data found  do something 
      
      gather_txn[j,1] <- j # add a record for iteration number 
      gather_txn[j,2] <- substr(linn[j],1,9) #get some substrings 
      gather_txn[j,3] <- substr(linn[j],34,39) #get some substrings 
      
    }  
  }
  i <- i + 1
 }
```

Comment: I think something might be wrong with your indexing. I`ve expected a global counting variable to increase the index for every added row, e.g. `count <- 1` before starting the loop and the `count <- count + 1` for increasing the loop if(...)==T. Then `gather_txn[count, 1]` and so on should be used. If you provide a minimal reproducible example I can provide you a code as a solution.

Comment: #JKupzig thank you for the help. I solved it

Comment: Why is the outer loop a `while` loop rather than a `for` loop?

Comment: @KonradRudolph for no reason, it could be written in a for loop as well.

Comment: Right, and using a `for` loop would simplify the code, even if only slightly. Writing the simplest code possible pays outsized dividends in the long run, because complexity compounds, and seemingly small complexities add together to make code *much* harder to understand.

Comment: I totally agree, sometimes we write code fast and don't think of those points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looping through the wrong variable. the inside if loop needs to add to the table using **i** not **j** variable:

```
gather_txn[i,1] <- j # add a record for iteration number 
gather_txn[i,2] <- substr(linn[j],1,9) #get some substrings 
gather_txn[i,3] <- substr(linn[j],34,39) #get some substrings
```